# Variable syntax in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of MATLAB code that I want to translate to python, here is the relevant part of code:

assuming `x = [1,2,3,4,5]`:

```
% The size of x
N=size(x);
N=N(2);
```

The issue is at the second line. I understand the index syntax if it was say `x(2)`, but `N(2)` I don't understand. I've tried looking at what this means in the documentation, but all I could find was for indexing lists.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I can answer. But please combined your answer attempt to your question body and specify the type of `x` for better readability for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in official documentation of [`size()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html),

> `sz = size(A)` returns a row vector whose elements are the lengths of the corresponding dimensions of A. For example, if `A` is a 3-by-4 matrix, then `size(A)` returns the vector `[3 4]`.

where `A` is any array.

In Matlab, the first dimension is row. Second is column. `N(2)` returns the 2nd element of this vector. As explained in the documentation, that is the length of the 2nd dimension. And 2nd means the column index.

Some cases are of note:

Arrays in Matlab are allowed to have any number of dimensions. Nonetheless, it is always considered as having at least 2 dimensions. That is, a column vector is an N-by-1 2D array; a row vector is a 1-by-N 2D array; a scalar is a 1-by-1 2D array.

In case `x` is a column vector, `N(2)` is still a valid statement with valid return, which is 1 because the length of the 2nd dimension of `x` in this case is 1.

If `x` is a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html), which is always a 1-by-1 array, `size(x)` will still have valid output, even if unintuitively at first. And so `N(2)` will be 1. If `x` is some other program defined [class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html), such as a Java object, be careful not to mix up `size(x)` with `x.size()`. `x` may still be a 1-by-1 array of the program-defined type in the context of Matlab. And thus `size(x)` may return `[1 1]` while `x.size()` might have other meanings.

---

Above is also equivalent as getting the second output parameter `sz2` as follows.

> `[sz1,...,szN] = size(___)` returns the lengths of the queried dimensions of A separately.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but assumed it didn't apply for 1D list. Thanks.

Comment: @gothere: I see. Actually I will edit my answer to comment on column and row vector x. (But hey, that's where information on x helps reminding things :P)

Comment: “If x wasn't even an array to begin with” — everything in MATLAB is an array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Will function handle and program-defined classes also be automatically an array?

Comment: User-defined classes are arrays by default as well (you can overload indexing, making it look like it's not an array). Function handles are always 1x1 arrays (size returns [1,1]), you cannot put more into the array because the `()` indexing operator is overloaded to do function call instead. But still, it's a good mental model to think of everything in MATLAB being an array, it certainly helped me. Also, in a MEX-file you see every value being represented as an `mxArray` object.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I see. I just wasn't sure about those two cases. I'll edit my answer